# Python 3 bluetooth connection ports

Tags: python, bluetooth

AFAIK bluetooth uses profiles to determine which type of device it should connect to.
Using Pyhton3 i can create a socket server to bind to a port, but where do the profiles go?
I am trying to connect to my phone using this app, but i cannot set a port there: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=de&gl=US

I can't find any code in python managing the bluetooth profiles. AFAIK the app uses the serial profile, but is that what python sockets are?

Comment: What operating system are you running on? Can you update your question with the code that you have created so far?